# Как удалить setTimeout, спустя несколько часов?

Tags: javascript, discord

При вводе команды бот дает ответ: Привет! Далее, спустя 2ч (написано через setTimeout) высвечивается сообщение в чат: Если ты еще не освоился, перейди в канал ...
Далее нужно удалить именно это сообщение, но спустя лишь несколько часов.
clearTimeout поэтому не подходит, у него нет параметров времени.

Comment: А что мешает запустить `clearTimeout` через `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно почему вы говорите о `clearTimeout()`..

Если я правильно понял, у вас должно быть "два ожидания": сначала через 2 часа выводим сообщение, потом через 2 часа мы его же удаляем.

Следовательно нужно два таймера:

```
let delay = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 2 часа
// Запускаем первый таймер, по истечению которого показываем сообщение
let timer = setTimeout(() => {

  // Тут вы выводите сообщение и сохраняете в переменную ID сообщение, чтобы потом удалить его.

  // Запускаем второй таймер, где уже удалим сообщение
  timer = setTimeout(() => {
    // Удаляем сообщение.
  }, delay);
}, delay);
```

---

> clearTimeout поэтому не подходит, у него нет параметров времени.

А вы читали [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout)?

```
const timer = setTimeout(() => { // Запускаем таймер
  clearTimeout(timer); // Очищаем его.
  alert('Если ты еще не освоился, перейди в канал ...');
}, 2 * 60 * 1000)
```

А вообще, это не обязательно делать, т.к. он выполняет один раз, в отличии от setInterval(), что запускается через каждый `delay`.